# Is there a Yiddish loanword for unnecessary work?

Tags: single-word-requests, yiddish

Does there exist an English word of Yiddish origin meaning “bothersome busywork” (admittedly redundant)?
Is that what “chazzerai” means?  (I’m sure that's spelled incorrectly)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about the English Language.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking about Yiddish loanwords used in English, right?

Comment: Yes, words originating in Yiddish but in common English usage.  E.g., schmuck, schtup, verklempt.  
There’s a whole question topic “Yiddish” on this site;  I don’t understand why my question needs to be deep-sixed…?!

Comment: *Chazzerai* is closer to garbage, nonsense - an all-purpose sneer. Literally *pork* in the plural, and the original aversion.

Comment: Is there any reason for thinking there is a loanword, such as a place you may have seen it, or are you just guessing?

Comment: Some Yiddish loanwords have entered the English vernacular but "chazzerai" [?] and verklempt are not two of them.

Comment: *"words originating in Yiddish but in common English usage."* Obviously, after 53 views so far, this word is not common and probably is not a loan word. You can find lists of common Yiddish words on the internet without much difficulty.

Comment: *Verklempt* is without question entering English. There are a number of hits in today's Google News, including the [*Milwaukee Record*](https://milwaukeerecord.com/food-drink/enjoy-milwaukee-record-blend-coffee-donuts-and-local-music-with-us-at-anodyne-on-november-26/) and a headline in the [*Toronto Star*](https://www.thestar.com/entertainment/books/damned-if-i-wasn-t-wiping-tears-and-holding-back-sniffles-read-the-book-that/article_45e5435d-1b5d-50f4-bb4d-b974c67fbcff.html). It's not that infrequently heard on television, either.

Comment: An old Mike Myers comedy skit  on *Saturday Night Live* gave *verklempt*  a big boost.

Answer (score 2):

Leo Rosten, *Hooray for Yiddish: A Book About English* (1982) offers the following entry for *khazer*:

> **Khazer** (standard) | khazeray | chazzer | chozzer
>
> [Pronunciation:] Rattle the *kh*: KHAH-z'r and kha-z'RY. Hebrew: pig.
>
> [Meanings:] 1. Pig. 2. A greedy lout; a glutton. 3. An ungrateful type. 4. A cheap selfish person. 5. One who takes advantage of another, through cheap tricks or cunning tactics.
>
> Oddly enough, given the ancient taboo on the porcine, Jews rarely use *khazer* to describe someone dirty, as English speakers do when they snap "Pig!"
>
> *Kahazerish*, the adjective, is used (also oddly enough) with a tinge of envy: "He lives a *khazerish tug*" means "He's living it up."
>
> *Khazeray* means awful food, cheap merchandise, obscenity, or contemptible reading. I much prefer *khazeray* to its colloquial synonym, "crap." Its sonic lilt is enough to recommend it.

So if the word you heard as "chazzerai" is the same one that Rosten identifies as *khazeray*, it has far broader application in Yiddish than is implied by the specific sense "bothersome busywork." Certainly one might refer to "bothersome busywork" as "crap" (I think that I have, on more than one occasion)—but the world is full of things that qualify colloquially as "crap."

With regard to whether *khazeray* has crossed over from Yiddish to English to any meaningful extent, I think that the answer is unequivocally no. For evidence that this is the case, I point to the fact that Rosten, in his book *The Joys of Yinglish* 1989)—which advertises itself as "An exuberant dictionary of Yiddish words, phrases and locutions that are now part of the English language or, because of their incomparable connotations, should be"—contains no entry for *khazer* or *khazeray* (in any spelling). Evidently, the fact that *khazeray* is comparable to "crap" goes a long way toward rendering it dispensable in English.

Comment: For more about [*khazer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=d1EnrsjzBMUC&pg=PA73&dq=khazer+yiddish&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ-PzYpOGCAxUqFFkFHbOAD2UQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=khazer%20yiddish&f=false), see  Michael Wex's *Born to Kvetch: Yiddish Language and Culture in All Its Moods*, pp.72-73.